# Magento 2: How/Where is the `getTemplate` Knockout Function Bound?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

Many Magento backend pages contain the following in their source code

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

I understand (or think I do?) that `<!-- ko template` is a KnockoutJS [container-less template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

What's not clear to me is -- what context is the `getTemplate()` function called in?  In the examples I've see online, there's usually a javascript object after the `template:`.  I'm assuming that `getTemplate` is a javascript function that returns an object -- but there's no *global* javascript function named `getTemplate`.

Where is `getTemplate` bound?  Or, possibly a better question, where does the KnockoutJS application binding happen on a Magento backend page?

I'm interested in this from a pure HTML/CSS/Javascript point of view.  I know Magento 2 has many configuration abstractions so (in theory) developers don't need to worry about the implementation details.  I'm interested in the implementation details.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The PHP code for a UI component renders a javascript initialization that looks like this

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app":{
                "types":{...},
                "components":{...},
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This bit of code in the page means Magento will invoke the `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` RequireJS module to fetch a callback, and then call that that callback passing in the the `{types:..., components:...}` JSON object as an argument (`data` below)

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/core/app.js
define([
    './renderer/types',
    './renderer/layout',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/ko/initialize'
], function (types, layout) {
    'use strict';

    return function (data) {
        types.set(data.types);
        layout(data.components);
    };
});
```

The data object contains all the **data** needed to render the UI component, as well as a configuration that links certain strings with certain Magento RequireJS modules.  That mapping happens in the `types` and `layout` RequireJS modules.  The application also loads the `Magento_Ui/js/lib/ko/initialize` RequireJS library.  The `initialize` module kicks off Magento's KnockoutJS integration.

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/** Loads all available knockout bindings, sets custom template engine, initializes knockout on page */

#File: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/ko/initialize.js
define([
    'ko',
    './template/engine',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-repeat',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-fast-foreach',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-es5',
    './bind/scope',
    './bind/staticChecked',
    './bind/datepicker',
    './bind/outer_click',
    './bind/keyboard',
    './bind/optgroup',
    './bind/fadeVisible',
    './bind/mage-init',
    './bind/after-render',
    './bind/i18n',
    './bind/collapsible',
    './bind/autoselect',
    './extender/observable_array',
    './extender/bound-nodes'
], function (ko, templateEngine) {
    'use strict';

    ko.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

Each individual `bind/...` RequireJS module sets up a single [custom binding](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings) for Knockout.

The `extender/...` RequireJS modules add some helper methods to native KnockoutJS objects.

Magento also extends the functionality of Knockout's javascript template engine in the `./template/engine` RequireJS module.

Finally, Magento calls `applyBindings()` on the KnockoutJS object.  This is normally where a Knockout program would bind a view model to the HTML page -- however, Magento calls `applyBindings` **without** a view model.  This means Knockout will start processing the page as a view, but with no data bound.

In a stock Knockout setup, this would be a little silly.  However, because of the previously mentioned custom Knockout bindings, there's plenty of opportunities for Knockout to do things.

We're interested in the **scope** binding. You can see that in this HTML, also rendered by the PHP UI Component system.

```
<div class="admin__data-grid-outer-wrap" data-bind="scope: 'customer_listing.customer_listing'">
    <div data-role="spinner" data-component="customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns" class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">
        <div class="spinner">
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    </script>
</div>
```

Specifically, the `data-bind="scope: 'customer_listing.customer_listing'">` attribute.  When Magento kicks off `applyBindings`, Knockout will see this custom `scope` binding, and invoke the `./bind/scope` RequireJS module.  The ability to apply a custom binding is pure KnockoutJS.  The **implementation** of the scope binding is something Magento Inc. has done.

The implementation of the scope binding is at

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/ko/bind/scope.js
```

The important bit in this file is here

```
var component = valueAccessor(),
    apply = applyComponents.bind(this, el, bindingContext);

if (typeof component === 'string') {
    registry.get(component, apply);
} else if (typeof component === 'function') {
    component(apply);
}
```

Without getting too into the details, the `registry.get` method will pull out an already generated object using the string in the `component` variable as an identifier,  and pass it to the `applyComponents` method as the third parameter.   The string identifier is the value of `scope:` (`customer_listing.customer_listing` above)

In `applyComponents`

```
function applyComponents(el, bindingContext, component) {
    component = bindingContext.createChildContext(component);

    ko.utils.extend(component, {
        $t: i18n
    });

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(el.childNodes, ko.cleanNode);

    ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(component, el);
}
```

the call to `createChildContext` will create what is, essentially, a new viewModel object based on the already instantiated component object, and then apply it to all the descendant element of the original `div` that used `data-bind=scope:`.

So, what is the *already instantiated* component object?  Remember the call to `layout` back in `app.js`?

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/core/app.js

layout(data.components);
```

The `layout` function/module will descend into the passed in `data.components` (again, this data comes from the object passed in via `text/x-magento-init`).  For each object it finds, it will look for a `config` object, and in that config object it will look for a `component` key.  If it finds a component key, it will

1. Use `RequireJS` to return a module instance -- as though the module were called in a `requirejs`/`define` dependency.
2. Call that module instance **as a javascript constructor**
3. Store the resulting object in the `registry` object/module

So, that's a lot to take in.  Here's a quick review, using

```
<div class="admin__data-grid-outer-wrap" data-bind="scope: 'customer_listing.customer_listing'">
    <div data-role="spinner" data-component="customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns" class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">
        <div class="spinner">
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    </script>
</div>
```

as a starting point.  The `scope` value is `customer_listing.customer_listing`.

If we look at the JSON object from the `text/x-magento-init` initialization

```
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            /* snip */
            "components": {
                "customer_listing": {
                    "children": {
                        "customer_listing": {
                            "type": "customer_listing",
                            "name": "customer_listing",
                            "children": /* snip */
                            "config": {
                                "component": "uiComponent"
                            }
                        },
                        /* snip */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We see the `components.customer_listing.customer_listing` object has a `config` object, and that config object has a `component` object that's set to `uiComponent`.  The `uiComponent` string is a RequireJS module.  In fact, its a RequireJS alias that corresponds to the `Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection` module.

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js
14:            uiComponent:    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection',
```

In `layout.js`, Magento has run code that's equivalent to the following.

```
//The actual code is a bit more complicated because it
//involves jQuery's promises. This is already a complicated 
//enough explanation without heading down that path

require(['Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection'], function (collection) {    
    object = new collection({/*data from x-magento-init*/})
}
```

For the really curious, if you take a look in the collection model and follow its execution path, you'll discover that `collection` is a javascript object that's been enhanced both by the `lib/core/element/element` module and the `lib/core/class` module.  Researching these customizations is beyond the scope of this answer.

Once instantiated, `layout.js` stores this `object` in the registry.  This means when Knockout starts processing the bindings and encounters the custom `scope` binding

```
<div class="admin__data-grid-outer-wrap" data-bind="scope: 'customer_listing.customer_listing'">
    <!-- snip -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- snip -->
</div>
```

Magento will fetch this object back out of the registry, and bind it as the view model for things inside the `div`.  In other words, the `getTemplate` method that's called when Knockout invokes the tagless binding (`<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->`) is the `getTemplate` method on the `new collection` object.

Comment: I hate to just ask the question 'why' to your answer,  so more focused question would be, what does M2 gain by using this (seemingly convoluted) system to call KO templates?

Comment: @circlesix Its part of a larger system for rendering `<uiComponents/>` from the layout XML system.  The benifits they get is the ability to swap view models on the same page for a different set of tags.

Comment: I don't know whether to laugh or cry! What a mess.

Comment: I think they are digging their own grave. If they keep complicating things like this, companies will stop using it because of development costs

Comment: I just spend around 5 hours trying to figure out how to bind a custom behaviour to a form thats rendered by all this "magic". One part of the problem is that this highly generic framework needs you to go through a ton of layers until you have a chance to understand how to do things. Also tracking where a certain configuration is coming from becomes incredibly tedious.

Comment: Why Magento, why?

Comment: Even very simple tasks are extremly difficult and time intensive. I start to hate magento.

Answer (score 18):

The binding for any of the knockout JS templates happens in the .xml files of the module. Using the Checkout module as an example you can find the config for the `content` template  in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                            </item>
```

In this file you can see that the block class has nodes that define the "jsLayout" and call out the `<item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">`. It's a little bit of a round robin of logic, but if you are in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml` you will see this line:

```
<div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

So the data-bind directs where to look for any nested template, in this case it's the `Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart` of `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js` for the logic (or MV in knockouts Model-View-View Model system) and you have `Magento_Checkout/minicart/content` (or V in knockouts Model-View-View Model system) for the template call. So the template that is being pulled in this spot is `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html`.

Really it's not to hard to figure out once you get use to looking in the .xml's. Most of this I learned [here](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-ui-knockoutjs-using-container-less-ko-template-gettemplate) if you can make your way past the broken English. But so far i feel like the Knockout integration is the least documented part of M2.

Comment: Useful information, so +1, but per the question, I know Magento has abstractions to deal with this -- but I'm curious about the implementation details themselves. i.e  -- when you configuration something in that XML file, magento does *something else* to make sure that your configured values *does a third thing*.  I'm interested in the something else and the third thing.

Comment: so when you look at ` <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->` in any `.phtml` file. it mean `.xml` file has this file in `<item name=" "/>` node.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the *global* `getTemplate` JS method you're looking for is defined under `app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/element/element.js` you can find it here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/4d71bb4780625dce23274c90e45788a72f345dd9/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/element/element.js#L262

As I'm on my phone I'm having a hard time finding out exactly how the binding is getting done.