# How Does Magento 2 Apply KnockoutJS Bindings

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, knockoutjs

Per a very cursory reading of the KnockoutJS documentation, initializing a very basic Knockout view looks like the following

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

i.e. -- you create a javascript function intended to be used as an object constructor, instantiate an object from it, and then pass that object into the `ko.applyBindings` method of the global knockout object (`ko`)

However, in Magento 2, if you load a backend page with a Grid UI, Magento will initialize the `js/core/app.js` RequireJS module

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    './renderer/types',
    './renderer/layout',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/ko/initialize'
], function (types, layout) {
    'use strict';

    return function (data) {
        types.set(data.types);
        layout(data.components);
    };
});
```

This module, in turn, loads the `Magento_Ui/js/lib/ko/initialize` module, which *appears* to initialize Magento's use of KnockoutJS.  However, if you look at the source of initialize module.

```
define([
    'ko',
    './template/engine',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-repeat',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-fast-foreach',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-es5',
    './bind/scope',
    './bind/staticChecked',
    './bind/datepicker',
    './bind/outer_click',
    './bind/keyboard',
    './bind/optgroup',
    './bind/fadeVisible',
    './bind/mage-init',
    './bind/after-render',
    './bind/i18n',
    './bind/collapsible',
    './bind/autoselect',
    './extender/observable_array',
    './extender/bound-nodes'
], function (ko, templateEngine) {
    'use strict';

    ko.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

You see Magento's called the `ko.applyBindings();` object **without a view object**.  This doesn't make any sense, and I'm not sure if it's my limited understanding of Knockout, or Magento doing something custom/strange here.

Is this where Magento actually applies Knockout bindings? Or does that happen somewhere else?  Or is Magento doing something tricky to intercept Knockout code and process it elsewhere?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `Magento_Ui/js/lib/ko/initialize` library is, indeed, where Magento initializes its Knockout instance.   Magento **does not** assign a ViewModel when it applies bindings.

The missing key here is the [custom KnockoutJS binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) named `scope`.

When Magento's Knockout instance encounters a `scope:` binding like this

```
<li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : 'Default welcome msg!'"></span>
</li>
```

It takes the value of that binding (named `customer`), and uses it to load and apply a ViewModel for the inner nodes from the `uiRegistry`.  You can debug the data bound for a particular scope with some simple KnockoutJS `pre` debugging

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'someScope'">
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>            
</div>
```

The `uiRegistry` is a simple dictionary like object, implemented in the `Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry` RequireJS module.

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js
17:            uiRegistry:     'Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry',
```

Objects are put into the registry via the bits of javascript that look like this

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "customer": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer",
                    "extra_data_1":"some_value",
                    "more_extra":"some_other_value",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The program in the `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` module will examine the `components` key of the passed in object, and for each sub-object will

1. Fetch the object returned by the specified `RequireJS` module from the `component` key (`Magento_Customer/js/view/customer`)
2. Use that object to instantiate a **new** javascript object (see below)
3. Assign any extra data keys to that same object
4. Add that same object to the `uiRegistry` with the key of the original object (`customer` above)

If you're not sure how the `x-magento-init` script works, [I've written an article about it here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts).

There's a more in depth examination of the `app.js` process [over in this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120508/4).

The implementation of the scope binding is defined here

```
vendor/magento//module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/ko/bind/scope.js
```

Comment: Alan it's a great answer! Thank you for the information. Regarding bullet point 3 how will it add extra data keys to the newly instantiated object. Will it be properties or something else?